# A problem about matrices in $M_{(n\times k)} [\mathbb Z]$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B,C\in M_{(n\times k)} [\mathbb Z]$. In which conditions we can achieve $AC^T$ from $AB^T$ just by interchanging some appropriate columns (or rows) with each other  ?!

(For example if we interchange column 2 with column 5 of $AB^T$ we can have $AC^T$.)

Note that $M_{(n\times k)} [\mathbb Z]$ is the set of $n\times k$ matrices with entries in integers.

Comment: Please show your efforts for solving the question to get positive response from the community.

Comment: What do you mean by 'achieve' and 'changing'?

Comment: @AnyAD by 'changing' i mean replacing and by ;achieve' i mean: for example if we replace column 2 with column 5 of $AC^T$ we can have $AB^T$

Comment: How is $AB^T$ Even defined? $A$ And $B^T$  are $n\times k$ matrices

Comment: B is a $k\times n$ matrix. Hence $B^T$ will be an $n\times k$ matrix.

Comment: @fierydemon yes you are true i edit it, thanks. Now look at it again

Comment: "if we replace column 2 with column 5 of $AC^T$ we can have $AB^T$" Do you mean that $AB^T$ has both columns 2 and 5 identical or are you interchanging the columns?

Comment: @N8tron We are interchanging columns with each other.It means that column 2 of $AB^T$ is column 5 of $AC^T$ and column 5 of $AB^T$ is column 2 of $AC^T$.

Comment: @mahdimeisami I'd edit your post to use the word **interchanging** or **switching** instead of replacing. Many texts use replacement for their addition operation.

Comment: @N8tron thanks for your comment, i changed it.